# python cprofile shows lot of information. Can it be limited to only my code

Tags: python, cprofile

`cProfile` shows lot of built-in function calls in the output. Can we limit the output only to the code I have written. So in the below example, can i see only the lines from `testrun` or the functions called from `testrun()` which resides in the same script. Or may be limit the level of calls logged to 2 or 3 ?

```
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
testrun()
pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='time')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the output as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695501/limiting-the-results-of-cprofile-to-lines-containing-something-and-or-somet).

So, for example, you could filter by your modules name, c.f., [`print_stats()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.print_stats):

```py
pr.sort_stats("time").print_stats("dir_or_module_name")  # replace dir_or_module_name
```

Just make sure **not** to call [`strip_dirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.strip_dirs) before, as that would possibly remove your directory/module name.

---

Edit: you can even filter by multiple names, as `print_stats()` should accept a regex:

```py
pr.print_stats("dir1|dir2|module1")
```